# 80s 90s movie involving a futuristic society with no crime

Tags: story-identification, movie, dystopia

I'm looking for a movie. From what I remember, all cars are white and unlocked, as in nobody commits any crime. If you commit a crime, the public chases you with baseball bats.

There's something about removing part of your brain if you don't comply. (This might be two different movies.) I remember that the guy didn't agree with brain surgery, so they sent him to a remote location. He found a gun with one bullet, but before killing himself discovered that there are other people living there. Then the movie ends.

Comment: If there was a joke about three seashells instead of toilet paper, it's an easy answer. But that wouldn't fit with the public chasing anyone with baseball bats, unfortunately.

Comment: No crime and white cars makes me think Minority Report, but again, I don't remember any baseball bats. It is a rather evocative detail... not many futuristic societies that have eliminated crime that have civilians with baseball bats enforcing it...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is the TV movie, ***[Tempting Fate](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0137156/)*** (1998).

> A brain surgeon lost his chance to be with his dream girl and opts for a friend's invention bringing him to a parallel world, where the dream girl is "his" widow.

In late 1990s Los Angeles, a scientist named Emmett Lach invents a device that enables him to travel to an alternate Los Angeles in a parallel universe.

At first glance, the alternate LA seems nicer than the one he's from. It's cleaner, people seem friendlier, Elvis Presley is still alive, and all cars (except for police cars) are common property; the doors are left unlocked and no keys are required to start the engines. They're also all the same model and colour (white).

> [image: Image of identical white cars from "Tempting Fate" (1998).]
>
> <sub>*Tempting Fate* (1998)</sub>

Emmett fears that if he wanders too far from the equipment he uses to transport himself back & forth between the two universes, he won't be able to return home, so he enlists two friends to explore the other world for him; a brain surgeon named Ben Creed (the protagonist of the film) and a dentist named John Bollandine.

It eventually transpires that the other world isn't as nice as it seemed. People diagnosed with mental disorders are forced to undergo a type of lobotomy called an 'alteration' in order to correct their behaviour. There's a also a 'game' in which seemingly random individuals are named on television news broadcasts and then chased and beaten to death by hordes of civilians wielding baseball bats.

> [image: Image of a fugitive encircled by people with baseball bats from "Tempting Fate" (1998).]
>
> <sub>*Tempting Fate* (1998)</sub>

John winds up being arrested by the police for the crime of "gross obesity in a public place" and is given the choice to either undergo an alteration or be sentenced to isolation in a remote cabin in the Sierras. He chooses the latter option, and when he arrives at the cabin, he finds a gun with a single bullet in it in a locked drawer, and presumes that he's expected to ultimately commit suicide due to loneliness.

He actually considers doing so, until he realises that he's not alone after all. To his relief, he sees other friendly people emerging from the surrounding forest, apparently having been sentenced to isolation like he was.

> [image: Image of people sentenced to isolation in the Sierras from "Tempting Fate" (1998).]
>
> <sub>*Tempting Fate* (1998)</sub>

I couldn't find an English-language version of the film (or even a trailer) on YouTube, but here's a video where a fan of the film describes some of the plot and shows a few relevant clips.

Comment: That's it that's the movie! Thank you very much. I have tried googling the description and using chatgpt and nothing. Thank you LogicDictates.

Comment: Man, that's got quite a cast.

Comment: I was actually about to ask the very same question - I remember watching it back around the turn of the millenium - it is available in English in various places.
It's available in some areas (not mine) on Prime Video and various archives out there... Do check up on the legality first - if you want to respect that :-)